# Using "this" within $.ready within prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, this

How do I pass in a variable proxy of the "this" context of the Class instance? For example, this.saySomething() isn't doing what I'd like it to.

Do you have any other recommendations on OOJS code organization?

```
// Truveo Video Player Class
function Player(){

    // Player Defaults
    this.opts = {
        volume: 0 // Initial volume settings
    };
}

// Initialize player setup / methods
Player.prototype.init = function(configs){

    // Overwrite defaults with custom configs
    this.opts = $.extend(this.opts, configs);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        this.saySomething();
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
        // do something else
    });
}

Player.prototype.saySomething = function(){
    alert(this.opts.volume);
}

// Create instance for channel surf
var configs = {volume:10};
var cSurf = new Player();
cSurf.init(configs);
```

Comment: I'm sure you tried but check what `this` is with `alert(this)` see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save a copy of `this` before entering the function:

```
var me = this;
$(document).ready(function(){
    me.saySomething();
});
```

Comment: That worked, but I'm surprised. I thought creating a var as such equated to a private var that wasn't accessible elsewhere?

Comment: Also, is it correct to be creating the opts defaults in the creation of the class? Or should I be doing that in some prototype call?

Comment: @Matrym, yes `var me` is private to the `init` function, but because the handler function for `.ready` is created within `init`, it gains a **closure** that captures references to each local variable in `init`.

Comment: @Matrym, it is correct to be creating `opts` in the constructor function because a new instance of opts must be created for each new instance of `Player`. Prototypes are shared so attaching `opts` to `prototype` won't work.

Comment: Thank you, you've been very helpful in helping me take the OOJS step :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175787/using-this-within-ready-within-prototype/5175803#5175803) from [@Box9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405143/box9), one possibility would be to set the value of `this` for the entire `.ready()` call.

You can do this with the [`jQuery.proxy()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method.

```
$(document).ready( $.proxy(function(){
    this.saySomething();
}, this) );
```

Now in the function that's sent to `.ready()` it will have your `Player` object as the value of `this`.